# CMake rebuilts custom target despite no sources having changed

Tags: cmake, build, code-generation, cmake-custom-command

I'm using a custom target in a CMake file of mine, which looks like this:

```
add_custom_target(generated_bar
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DOUT=bar -P generate-bar.cmake
    BYPRODUCTS bar
    COMMENT "Generating bar from foo"
    SOURCES foo)
```

This works fine for me, and `bar` gets generated. However, if I `make generated_bar` again - `bar` gets generated again, even though the source file `foo` has not changed.

Why is this happening?

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44054266/1593077) is related.

Comment: You probably expect options `BYPRODUCTS` and `SOURCES` are for specifying *dependencies*, but they are not. According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), `SOURCES` specifies files for IDE only, and `BYPRODUCTS` is used only by Ninja generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom *target* is always considered to be out of date, so its command always runs. However, that does not extend to its dependencies:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT bar
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DOUT=bar -P generate-bar.cmake
  DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generate-bar.cmake" foo
  COMMENT "Generating bar from foo"
)

add_custom_target(
  generate_bar
  DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bar"
)
```

You should think of a custom target as like a `.PHONY` rule in Make... it's there to help you sequence things or to provide special utilities as build rules (that are not "built" as part of `ALL`)

Comment: Wow, the amount of code I'm going to have to write just to get a file to be compiled in two languages is staggering: A generator generation command, A generator invocation in the custom cuoomand, and a custom target to block the auto-rebuild...

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues ;)

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22779 :-(