# How do I tell Qt Creator to run my code generator to generate xxx.h and xxx.cpp file from xxx.txt file?

Tags: qt, cmake, dependencies

I wrote a C++ code generator program for code that provides access to Sql tables in QT. The generator takes a simple text file and produces a class header file (.h) and the class definition file (.cpp) pair. All the files are known to QT Creator in my project (and are under version control).

I want to have my code generator run when I change the input text file. I would then re-generate the .h and .cpp files corresponding to it. The build will then automatically compile the .cpp file when I build.

I don't know how to get my code generator into the QT Creator (cmake) build process. Can anyone help me?

I can run the process manually by selection each input text file and dropping it on the program. The is the capability to add a build step in QT Creator. I added my program as a "Custom Process Step", but it doesn't select each input text file, and use dependencies to decide to run or not.

A typical input text file look like this:

```
tablename=filepathtable,FP,dbt_filepath
filepath_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
drive_letter TEXT
file_path TEXT
full_path TEXT
```

The code generator creates a header file like this:

```
#ifndef DBT_FILEPATH_H
#define DBT_FILEPATH_H

// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! File was generated by dbtable_qt.ahk

#include "dbmanager.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>

class Dbt_Filepath
{
public:
    Dbt_Filepath(QSqlDatabase* p_db);
    bool createFPTable();
    bool insertFPTable();
  bool queryFPTablePrimaryKey(int p_filepath_id);

    void debugShowSqlQueryError(const QLatin1String& funcname,
                                QSqlQuery& query);
    const QString getTableName();

    // database table fields
    int filepath_id;
    QString drive_letter;
    QString file_path;
    QString full_path;
    enum eFP_dbcol{
          field_filepath_id=0,
          field_drive_letter,
          field_file_path,
          field_full_path };

    // private data and functions
private:
    QSqlDatabase* m_db;    // database
    void fillFieldsFromQuery(QSqlQuery& query);

};

#endif    // DBT_FILEPATH_H
```

and a .cpp file like this (partial shown):

```
// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! File was generated by dbtable_qt.ahk

#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include "dbt_filepath.h"

Dbt_Filepath::Dbt_Filepath(QSqlDatabase* p_db)
 : m_db(p_db)
{
}

const QString Dbt_Filepath::getTableName()
{
     const QString tblnm = QLatin1String("filepathtable");
     return tblnm;
}

bool Dbt_Filepath::createFPTable()
{
  bool success = false;
  const QLatin1String fname("DFP::createFPTable()");
  qDebug() << fname;
  QSqlQuery querycreate(*m_db);
  QString sqlcreate = QLatin1String(
          "CREATE TABLE filepathtable ("
          "filepath_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "drive_letter TEXT,"
          "file_path TEXT,"
          "full_path TEXT"
          ");"  );

  querycreate.prepare(sqlcreate);
  if (querycreate.exec())
    success = true;
  else
    debugShowSqlQueryError(fname, querycreate);
  return success;
}

bool Dbt_Filepath::insertFPTable()
{
  bool success = false;
  const QLatin1String fname("DFP::insertFPTable()");
  qDebug() << fname;
  QSqlQuery queryinsert(*m_db);
  QString sqlinsert = QLatin1String(
"INSERT INTO filepathtable ("
          "drive_letter,"
          "file_path,"
          "full_path"

           ") VALUES(?,?,?);");
  queryinsert.prepare(sqlinsert);
  queryinsert.addBindValue(drive_letter.toUtf8());
...
```

What I want is for the build process to use the input text files as sources - prior to compiling anything - to re-generate the c++ files, if required. Then I want to normal build process to proceed to compile and link my code.

Comment: Why not add a more sophisticated script as a "Custom Process Step"? And check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434055/cmake-copy-if-original-file-changed .

Comment: Pointing to "a more sophisticated script" which doesn't do what I want is really not productive. I am asking how to make a standard build construct using the QT build process. If it's not possible, the just say so.  If it's not possible, then how do I do it with specific targets in my .pro file?

Comment: I thought that you would use 'cmake' and that https://stackoverflow.com/a/8438510/4599792 would give you enough hints...